# CORS POST request throws on Authorization header

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, jestjs, jsdom

I'm trying to send a CORS POST request to my API and it throws a TypeError every time I use the 'Authorization' header. The request doesn't even get sent, so the server is not involved. But this only happens in my tests. When I try it in Chrome it works just fine.

**Here is the function that I'm testing:**

```
export const postNewEmployee = formData => {
  return fetch('http://localhost:3003', {
                             method: 'POST',
                             headers: {
                               'Authorization': 'Bearer test123',
                               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                             },
                             body: JSON.stringify(formData)
                           })
                           .then(response => response)
                           .catch(error => {
                             throw error;
                           });
  };
```

**And its test:**

```
import * as API from './api';
describe('postNewEmployee', () => {

  it('posts the form data asynchronously', () => {

    let formData = {
      employee: {
        name: 'Test Person',
        email: 'test@person.nu',
        address: 'an adress 123'
      }
    };

    return API.postNewEmployee(formData)
      .then(json => {
        expect(json.status).toEqual(201);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
});
```

The application is a react/redux app created with create-react-app, so I'm using Jest and JSDOM to test this. The thing is, if I comment out the Authorization header from the fetch()-call, it works fine. But if I add that header I get this:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Object.getRequestHeader (/Users/johanh/Kod/react-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:20:23)
    at setDispatchProgressEvents (/Users/johanh/Kod/react-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:909:38)
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (/Users/johanh/Kod/react-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:700:11)
    at /Users/johanh/Kod/react-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js:429:11
    at Object.<anonymous>.self.fetch (/Users/johanh/Kod/react-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js:373:12)
    at Object.<anonymous>.exports.postNewEmployee.formData [as postNewEmployee] (/Users/johanh/Kod/react-app/src/api/api.js:20:10)
    at Object.it (/Users/johanh/Kod/react-app/src/api/api.test.js:75:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/johanh/Kod/react-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine-async.js:42:32)
    at attemptAsync (/Users/johanh/Kod/react-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/vendor/jasmine-2.4.1.js:1919:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (/Users/johanh/Kod/react-app/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/vendor/jasmine-2.4.1.js:1874:9)
```

And as I said, this only happens in the test. In the browser it works fine.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I just can't see it. I've looked in the fetch spec and the jsdom documentation, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should not make real requests in a unit test. The best way to handle this is to use a mock instead of the real `fetch` implementation.

I assume you are using the JS implementation of `fetch`. So you can set `fetch` to what ever you want in your test.

```
import * as API from './api';
describe('postNewEmployee', () => {

  it('posts the form data asynchronously', () => {
    // set fetch to a mock that always returns a solved promise
    const fetch = jest.fn((url, options) => return Promise.resolve({status: 201}))
    global.fetch = fetch;
    let formData = {
      employee: {
        name: 'Test Person',
        email: 'test@person.nu',
        address: 'an adress 123'
      }
    };
    //test that fetch was called with the correct parameters
    expect(fetch.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('http://localhost:3003')
    expect(fetch.mock.calls[0][1]).toEqual(formData)
    return API.postNewEmployee(formData)
      .then(json => {
        expect(json.status).toEqual(201);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that I'm mocking the requests using nock. I just left that part out temporarily in order to isolate the problem. Since the request never gets sent to begin with, mocking makes no difference at the moment. Thanks for replying though :)

Comment: Even using nock,  a real request is made. And this should not happen in a unit test. Otherwise you would test the whole stack with lot of stuff that happen, which makes your test slow and unstable.

Comment: You have a point there. But still - even if sending the actual request is a bad idea, this *should* work. But I'll take your advice and just call a mock instead. Thanks for the help!